# Create a custom query form (MS Access)

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have created an MS Access Form, an MS Access Query and a table depend on an excel file.
The form is named `CheckForm` and consists of a textfield for serialno, a search button (which has a makro to run a query) and a few fields with information, that should be filled by the query:
[image: MS Access Form]

The query is named `assets_ALT Abfrage - Serialno` and looks as follows:

```
SELECT Assets_ALT.STREETADDRESS, Assets_ALT.FLOOR, Assets_ALT.ROOM, Assets_ALT.DEPARTMENT, Assets_ALT.ITC_NAME, Assets_ALT.ASSET_USER_NAME, Assets_ALT.PERSONID, Assets_ALT.COMPUTER_NAME, Assets_ALT.CATEGORY, Assets_ALT.MANUFACTURER, Assets_ALT.PRODUCT, Assets_ALT.MODELL, Assets_ALT.SERIALNUM, Assets_ALT.MAC_ADDRESS
FROM Assets_ALT
WHERE (((Assets_ALT.SERIALNUM)=[Formulare]![CheckForm]![SearchSerialNo]));
```

The table with information, on which the query is built looks like this:
[image: MS Access Table]

When entering a serial no into the form like `F7D5H92`, clicking the `Suchen`-Button, the **form should be filled with the data from the query.**

*But it does not, instead the query is being opened (and showing no result):*
[image: Result]

Comment: Could you share some code to help us see the problem better?

Comment: I would, but I didn't do any coding. It was all by the designer

Answer (score 0):

New to this site, but may be able to assist. First, you'll want to create a table by selecting 'External Data' and using the 'Linked Table Manager' to connect your Access program to the external Excel file and add all fields from the file. Use the Seriennummer as the primary key to ensure there is only one listing for the seriennummer.

Once connected you will need to create a query that has the criteria that refers to the 'Seriennummer' textbox to link the file with your form. For example, set the query criteria for that field to  'Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![Search2] & "*"' if you form was named 'Search' and your textbox was named Search2. Then add a command button to your form and select the query to link the button to the query. Once you enter a serial number in the form and click the button, it should pull up the correct values on your form for that line item.

Comment: Thanks... the first paragraph I figured out.
But the second paragraph is where I am stuck. I have a query which asks the correct question (for the serial no) and provides me with the correct answer, but I don't know how to show this result in all these custom fields up in my screenshot

Comment: To show the fields, select the text boxes on the form (In Design View). Right click on them and select 'Properties'. A window should open on the right, and select the data tab. Click on 'Control Source'. You should then see a list of all the fields in the table linked to the form. Then select the field that you want to assign to each text box. When you refresh the form, it should show the correct information for the line/serial number you entered.

Comment: In 'Design View' select the 'Design' tab, then in the Controls section add the button to where you want it. You should get an option for the 'Command Button Wizard' asking what action you want. Select 'Miscellaneous' Then on the Actions side, Select 'Run Query'. It will then give you a list of available queries to run/connect the button to.

Comment: And then it jumps to the query... But doesn't find anything. But anyhow it should stay in the form and not open the query.